# Find maximum date from multiple embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

One of many documents in my collection is like below:

```
{ "_id" :123,
  "a"  :[
            { "_id" : 1,
              "dt" :  ISODate("2013-06-10T19:38:42Z")
            },
            { "_id" : 2,
              "dt" :  ISODate("2013-02-10T19:38:42Z")
            }
      ],
  "b"  :[
            { "_id" : 1,
              "dt" :  ISODate("2013-02-10T19:38:42Z")
            },
            { "_id" : 2,
              "dt" :  ISODate("2013-23-10T19:38:42Z")
            }
      ],
  "c"  :[
            { "_id" : 1,
              "dt" :  ISODate("2013-03-10T19:38:42Z")
            },
            { "_id" : 2,
              "dt" :  ISODate("2013-13-10T19:38:42Z")
            }
      ]
}
```

I want to find the maximum date for the whole document (a,b,c).
The solution i have right now is, I loop through all root `_id` then do a `$match` in aggregation framework for each `a`, `b`, `c` for every root document. this sounds very inefficient, any better ideas?

Comment: you mean the maximum of all dates in a, b and c?

Comment: If the keys like a,b,c aren't known in advance, you'll need to try a map reduce. Have you tried that?

Comment: @innoSPG yes..........

Comment: Two options: Brute force + threading, or flatten the tree and sort them.

Comment: If the type of queries you want to run against your collection can't be cleanly supported by your schema, you should consider changing your schema to one that does.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554974/mongo-sort-by-multiple-fields-in-a-nested-array).  Check it out.

As with that solution, your issue can be handled with MongoDB's aggregation framework, using the `$project` and `$cond` operators to repeatedly flatten your documents while preserving a max value at each step.